# android downloading multiple files and mapping to activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an XML which contains an array of books. The array will contain url to download bimpat image. book id and book name.

e.g.

```
<result>
<books>
<book>
<bookId>101</bookId>
<bookname>java</bookname>
<bookurl><http://bookimage.jpg>
</book>
<book>
<bookId>102</bookId>
<bookname>c++</bookname>
<bookurl><http://bookimage.jpg>
</book>
<book>
<bookId>103</bookId>
<bookname>.net</bookname>
<bookurl><http://bookimage.jpg>
</book>
</books>
```

The above xml is downloaded and stored in array and individual image is downloaded from each URL. Mean while book data is set in activity.

If the image download is done serially it takes a lot of time. If done parallely , i do not come to know which image corresponds to which book.

```
public class myasync extends asynctask
{
doInBackground(String url)
{
Bitmap bitmap = getfilefromurl;
return bitmap;
}
}

public class activity1 extends Activity
{


OnCreate()
{
 myasync myasyncobj = new myasync(this);
 myasyncobj .execute("http://bookimage.jpg");
}
```

}

The image is returned to activity. But it is not known to which book id it correspond.

EDIT: I am planning to use hashmap to return URL and bitmap. But returning hashmap containing only one key value pair, might not be a good idea. Is there any construct for storing one string and bitmap?

EDIT2: I am sharing activity object. Can create an interface also. 
`Interface.setBitmap()`  , `Interface.setURL()`. But creating new interface for sharing one bitmap and one url, will be good programming practice?

EDIT 3: The solution I have used is to create an class for storing bitmap and url. This will be called from OnPostExecute.

```
class BitmapURLMap
{
   Bitmap bmp;
   String URL;
}
Class Book
{
  String URL;
  String BookID;
  String IconImage;

  //getter and setter methods.
}

Class model //model for mvp
{
  ArrayList<Book> arrBook = null;

  public void setBookArr(ArrayList<Book> arrBook  )
  {
    this.arrBook  = arrBook ;
  }

  public ArrayList<Book> arrBook  getBookArr( )
  {
    return arrBook ;
   }
}

    public class myasync extends asynctask
    {
      Activity activity;
      public myasync(Activity activity)
      {
        this.activity = activity;
      }
        doInBackground(String url)
        {
          Bitmap bitmap = getfilefromurl;
          BitmapURLMap bmpURL = new BitmapURLMap(bitmap,url);
          return bmp;
        }
    OnPostExecute()
    {
       activity.setMap(bmpURL);
    }


public class activity1 extends Activity
{
    OnCreate()
     {
         myasync myasyncobj = new myasync(this);
         myasyncobj .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,"http://bookimage.jpg");
     }
     setMap(BitmapURLMap bmpURL)
     {
          ArrayList<Book> arrBook= model.getBookArr();
          for(Book book : arrBook)
          String URL = book.getURL();
          if(URL.equals( bmpURL.URL))
           {
             book.setIconImage(bmpURL.bmp);
             break;
           }
      model.setBookArr(arrBook);
      }
}
```

But I am sure this solution is not the right way to do it. Though it works.
Can someone tell me how to implement it the right way.

Comment: Share your asyncTask, or if you know how to use an `Interface` or `Handler`, use it to recognize which image pertains to which url.

Comment: Isnt handler is for sharing data between 2 threads. OnPostExecute() is already running on ui thread. So handlers are the right thing to use?

Comment: let me clear some doubts, is your asynctask is a different class? Can't you post its code here?

Comment: yes its different, the code is already posted above.

Comment: This is your whole code? I mean you are not even making object for asyncTask class, Then how are you doing it?

Comment: Well, for starters you should not pass an activity instance to your AsyncTask object. You could use a a thread and handler approach, the thread for download and the handler to notify your clients (activity) that a download has finished; For multiple parallel downloads you can use a ThreadPoolExecutor or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: Ok. Means AysncTask should not be used in the first place. Instead thread and handlers should be used.

Comment: I had read somewhere that async tasks internally use threads and handlers . But now I  think with thread and handlers, reattaching the activity to the handler is easier on configuration changed, that is why using thread and handlers must be better? infact i am yet to figure out a way to reattach my activity object to aysnc task.